# Unable to load magento class using Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, magento, namespaces

I am using Laravel 5 and magento 1.9.
Firstly see my file structure of my server :
[image]

Running Laravel project under main domain. Magento is installed in **MagentoDir**. **LaravelProjectDir** is the Laravel project directory.

In `/LaravelProjectDir/app/Http/Controllers/controller1.php` I wrote :

```
<?php
    //some code, namespacing ...etc
    require_once('/home/domain/public_html/magentoDir/app/Mage.php');
    class UserController extends Controller{
         //my functions
    }
?>
```

This error is thrown :

> FatalErrorException in functions.php line 95: Cannot redeclare __() (previously declared in /home/domain/public_html/LaravelProjectDir/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:850)

Please ask if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the same function is decalred in `app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php` that is `function __()` which is translator function so if you dont need that function then you can comment it out.

in **magento** : **app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php** comment out following function

```
function __()
{
    return Mage::app()->getTranslator()->translate(func_get_args());
}
```

Comment: I commented that out. Then I run `$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');` which throws **include(App\Http\Controllers\Mage.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**